# Google API refresh token CURL

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I connecting the google spreadsheet API. I have already granted permission to the user and retrieved the code. I would like to refresh the token with the refresh token, but cannot find the url. can anyone point me to the url needed? I cannot use the libraries since I am using an ETL tool and not a code to connect to the service.

Thank you

Nir

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token \
  -d client_id=$CLIENT_ID \
  -d client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET \
  -d refresh_token=$REFRESH_TOKEN \
  -d grant_type=refresh_token
```

Comment: When I do this I get back a 400 Bad Request saying "unsupported_grant_type" with an error description of "Invalid grant_type". Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For the first authorization code exchange, a refresh token is obtained in offline scenarios. In these cases, your application may obtain a new access token by sending a refresh token to the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization server.

As discussed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#obtainingatoken), to obtain a new access token, your application sends an HTTPS POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`.